# fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, preprocessor, linker-errors

I use Visual Studio 2010 Premium. I have two project A and B and I try to compile both to a 64-bit platform.
Project A outputs a .dll and a .lib file which project B relies on.
I already compiled successfully project A to a 64-bit platform, yet when I compile project B I get the following error :

> mfcs100d.lib(nolib.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

What could be the problem ? I don't really know what is this mfcs100d.lib file.
I've used "Dependency Walker" on project A's dll file and it seems to be relying solely on 64-bit dll files.
Additionally, I went to the Project B's (Property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced) and confirmed that 'Target Machine' is set to "MachineX64".
Also, On the Configuration Manager the Platform is set to x64.

Someone infromed me that the problem may be such :

Going to project B's (Property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> C\C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions) I have the following values there :

```
WIN32  
_DEBUG  
_WINDOWS  
_AFXEXT
```

Is that truly related ? Should I replace the 'WIN32' value ? if so, then how ? I don't really understand the meaning of those definitions and how to change them.

Edit : I just realized that probably it's not related at all. Those are simply definitions for the preprocessor, such as the ones which can be determined by a C++ #define command. Yet I could be wrong.

Comment: Don't get rid of WIN32, even compiling 64-bit code it's still the Win32 API so you need WIN32 defined.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty hard to get this wrong.  Start with Build + Configuration Manager and double-check that x64 is selected for both projects.  Next step is to verify the library search path.  Right-click the project, Properties, VC++ Directories, Library Directories.  Click on the combobox arrow to view the "Inherited values".  $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\amd64 should be the second in the list, that's where the 64-bit version of mfcs100d.lib is located.

Comment: The 1st value on the list is $(VCInstallDir)bin\x86_amd64
The 2nd is $(VCInstallDir)bin.  
How can I change the 1st value to $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\amd64 ? It seems like I can not rewrite this iteam and adding a new item caused me an error.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong setting, look at *Library Directories*, not Executable Directories.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry.
Yes, the value $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\amd64 is written there indeed, so I wonder to myself what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you add the x64 target, go into the General settings and look at Output Directory and Intermediate Directory.  For the Debug target change from "Debug" to "Debug64", same for Release target.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of this please?